# use variable inside @Url.Action ()

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this code that needs to refer to different ActionResults in the Home Controller. The ActionResut will change depending in the "num" Jquery var.
But when i concatenate "num" says that the name "num" do not exist in the current context.

```
var num = 2;
var cat = movie;
```

@Url.Action(num)

```
$("#container").load("@Url.Action("TheAction" + num + ",Home")?category=" +   cat, function () {..more code here};
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The Url.Action method runs on your server when the page is rendered.  Which means your javascript variable isn't even a thing yet (nevermind that the server code is C# or VB and not javascript).  If you want to change the url the client is using via javascript, you will have to build it up by hand.